# When narrowing the screen, the cards do not change the number of rows

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

In general, I have cards that by default have four rows. And I want to make the number of rows in the version for tablets decrease to 2, and in the mobile version to 1. But in the end,  only displayed in 4 and in 1 row.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div class="mr10" fxFlex="25" fxFlex.lt-lg="50">
        <mat-card>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div class="mr10" fxFlex="25" fxFlex.lt-lg="50">
        <mat-card>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div class="mr10" fxFlex="25" fxFlex.lt-lg="50">
        <mat-card>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="25" fxFlex.lt-lg="50">
        <mat-card>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :[Refer](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API)

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-seed-jbz3gx?file=app/app.component.ts) use `mat-card` instead of message there

```
   <div fxLayout="row wrap">
        <div class="mr10" fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 25" fxFlex.gt-xs="0 1 calc(50% - 10px)" fxFlex="100">
            <mat-card>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div class="mr10" fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 25" fxFlex.gt-xs="0 1 calc(50% - 10px)" fxFlex="100">
            <mat-card>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div class="mr10" fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 25" fxFlex.gt-xs="0 1 calc(50% - 10px)" fxFlex="100">
            <mat-card>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex="25" fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 25" fxFlex.gt-xs="0 1 calc(50% - 10px)" fxFlex="100">
            <mat-card>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```